# How Does This CSS Only Parallax Work?

Tags: html, css

I've created a parallax scrolling effect using only CSS. However I'm struggling to understand why it's actually working. Can someone help explain.

**HTML**

```
<div class="image"></div>
<section class="content">
    <p>TEXT GOES HERE</p>       
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.image {
    background: url('http://s28.postimg.org/v6mfcxbyl/galaxy.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 500px;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It looks like it has something to do with setting the background fixed on the image div.

Here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pAjNr/

Comment: No it works. But I don't know why...

Comment: Why do you expect it not to work? What is the difference between the expected behavior and the observed behavior?

Comment: This is not a parallax. A parallax effect is made with at least two moving elements where one of them is moving at a different speed/distance.

Comment: I would expect the page to just scroll regularly. Why does the content scroll over the image?

Comment: @gil Technically it is. They are moving at different speeds, the image isn't moving and the content is. That's a different speed if you ask me buddy.

Comment: because you're setting the background to 'fixed`

Comment: Actually it doesn't really scroll over. add `border:2px solid green;` to the `.image` class and you'll see what happens to the div when you scroll

Comment: Yes it does. Add `border:2px solid green;`to the `.content` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position:fixed` and `background-attachment:fixed` mean that the element will not move in relation to the viewport. So however much you scroll, the title (`position:fixed`) and the background image (`background-attachment:fixed`) will not move. The thing that does move is the text (`.content`) which doesn't have `position:fixed`.

When the text crosses over the title, it has a higher z-index (and `position:relative` so the z-index is not ignored) so it hides whatever is underneath it (the title).

Answer (score 2):

Statically fixed or relatively (according to document) position of the background image will create the background effect.

The title is positioned fixed with a `z-index` lower then the content this being covered by it on scroll.

The content below is just normal and on scroll it just covers all the fixed elements with lower `z-index`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the background to fixed will fix the background-image *relative to the viewport*, even when the element itself scrolls (see here with added border: [Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/pAjNr/4/) ).

You could as well position the `.image` element itself with `position:fixed` and add an offset for the `.content` element: [Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/pAjNr/2/) to achieve exactly the same effect.

Comment: That's interesting :)

Comment: @user3143218 any more questions?